# PlayFramework custom executors when using CompletableFutures and Java

Tags: java, playframework, concurrency, completable-future

In latest versions of PlayFramework they started using `CompletionStage` as return type for controllers that will be used for async execution or in a nutshell if you return `CompletionStage` it is asynchronous execution...

Now when we know the work we submit to `CF` is a long running `IO` operation we need to pass a custom executor (otherwise it will be executed on `FJP` by default).

Each controller execution has a `HTTP` context which has in it all the request information also this context is necessary to have your `EntityManagers` if you use `JPA`...

If we just create custom `ExecutorService` and inject it in our controller to use in `supplyAsync()` we won't have all the context information.

Here is an example of some controller action returning `CompletionStage`

```
return supplyAsync(() -> {
    doSomeWork();
  }, executors.io); // this is a custom CachedThreadPool with daemon thread factory
}
```

and if we try to run something like this in `doSomeWork()`

```
Request request = request(); // getting request using Controller.request()
```

or use preinjected `JPAAPI jpa` field in controller

```
jpa.withTransaction(
    () -> jpa.em() // we will get an exception here although we are wrapped in a transaction
             ...
);
```

exception like

```
No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try wrapping this call in JPAApi.withTransaction, or ensure that the HTTP context is setup on this thread.
```

As you can see the jpa code is wrapped in transaction but no context was found because this is a custom pure Java threadpool.

**What is the correct way to provide all the context information when using CompletableFuture and custom executor?**

I also tried defining custom executors in `application.conf` and lookup them from actor system but I will end up having `MessageDispatcher` which although is backed by `ExecutorService` is not compatible with `CompletableFuture` (maybe I'm wrong? if so how to use it with CF?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecution.fromThread`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/play/libs/concurrent/HttpExecution.html#fromThread-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) method:

> An `ExecutionContext` that executes work on the given `ExecutionContext`. The current thread's context `ClassLoader` and `Http.Context` are captured when this method is called and preserved for all executed tasks.

So, the code would be something like:

```
java.util.concurrent.Executor executor = getExecutorFromSomewhere();
return supplyAsync(() -> {
    doSomeWork();
}, play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecution.fromThread(executor));
```

Or, if you are using a `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext`:

```
scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext ec = getExecutorContext();
return supplyAsync(() -> {
    doSomeWork();
}, play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecution.fromThread(ec));
```

But I'm not entirely sure that will preserve the `EntityManager` for JPA.